# View, modify Assembly code during debug in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, memory, assembly

In Eclipse Debug mode I want to see the assembly level code, modify parts of it and rerun the program. The assembly level code should be the program code loaded into the memory for execution. I want to add breakpoints and then at those points modify the assembly code and reload the program.

Please let me know if this is doable. If yes, how can I do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the assembler code is easy: Simply open the "disassembly" view in Eclipse. You need the CDT toolset installed.

Modifying assembler code on x86 is not that easy: You can replace a piece of code that is X byte long by another piece of code that is also X bytes long.

Some debuggers (e.g. the MS-DOS-Debugger) had a built-in assembler; using other debuggers you'll have to modify the bytes in memory.

Unfortunately on x86 instructions have different size. So "mov eax,1" has 5 bytes and "mov ebx,1" has 6 bytes. So it is difficult simply replacing assembler code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked out the CDT Tool. It says it is for C/C++. Is there anything similar for Java?

Comment: Modifying a Java program is not possible that simply! You do not have machine code but byte code that can be interpreted by the virtual machine or translated to machine code depending on the optimization. Sometimes the virtual machine first interprets the byte code and later it translates it to machine code.